# If Statement give error with sqlite statement in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, if-statement, xcode7

I am learning the sqlite concept with iOS. At the learning stage I got stuck with with a problem, The problem is:

When i put NSLog after if statement it give no error. See the image:

[image]

But when I remove NSLog the compiler give me error, see the image:

[image]

Why this error come I have not find yet. My code are:

```
-(void)runQuery:(const char *)query isQueryExecutable:(BOOL)queryExecutable{
    sqlite3 *sqlite3Database;
    NSString *databasePath= [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFileName];

    if(self.arrResults != nil){
        [self.arrResults removeAllObjects];
        self.arrResults= nil;
    }
    self.arrResults =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if(self.arrColumnNames != nil){
        [self.arrColumnNames removeAllObjects];
        self.arrColumnNames= nil;
    }
    self.arrColumnNames= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    BOOL openDatabaseResult= sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String],&sqlite3Database);

    if(openDatabaseResult==SQLITE_OK)

        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        BOOL prepareStatementResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3Database,query,-1,&compiledStatement,NULL);


}
```

I am learning the sqlite tutorial from this link: https://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you attach your project here

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Please find the project https://www.dropbox.com/s/bv0h4rdv5cc01dn/SQLite3DB.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue appears to be that you've forgotten a bracket at the end of the if statement before that line.

```
if(openDatabaseResult==SQLITE_OK)

{
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    BOOL prepareStatementResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3Database,query,-1,&compiledStatement,NULL);
}
```

Comment: here you can download the project https://www.dropbox.com/s/hjn980hk3yueoje/Getting%20Started.pdf?dl=0 , the problem is same as excat my answer

Comment: in if condition if we write the more than 1 line we need to define if condition as { } else simple if without bracket we can define

Comment: @SaurabhJain - ha ha ha if you levaing the space also it shows error my bro

Comment: @SaurabhJain - FMDB is the third party, just like the AFNetworking, thats all